# How to use MS code coverage tool in command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, profiling, code-coverage

I have the following C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int testfunction(int input)
{
    if (input > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    testfunction(-1);
    testfunction(1);
}
```

I compiled it to get the execution

```
cl /Zi hello.cpp -link /Profile
```

Then, I instrument the execution and generated the .coverage binary.

```
vsinstr -coverage hello.exe
start vsperfmon -coverage -output:mytestrun.coverage
vsperfcmd -shutdown
```

When I open the coverage file in VS2010, I got nothing in its results.

[image]

What might be wrong?
I followed the instructions in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ms_joc/archive/2005/04/08/406608.aspx).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to run your program after the monitor starts:

1. `> vsinstr /coverage hello.exe`
2. `> start vsperfmon /coverage /output:mytestrun.coverage`
3. `> hello.exe`
4. `> vsperfcmd /shutdown`

When you run step 3, you should see some notification in vsperfmon.exe that hello.exe has started.

If you plan on doing multiple test runs, you only need to run steps 2-4.  In other words, you only need to instrument your binary (step 1) once after it's built.

Comment: Zam.  Why couldn't MS document it this easily?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299398(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: For future readers........here is a alternate solution to creating multiple .coverage files : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415562/mstest-code-coverage/37005493#37005493

Comment: Great, now how do we use the coverage file?