# How to publish results using dotnet test command

Tags: .net-core, command-line-arguments, dotnet-core-pack

I have a test project written in dotnet core. This need to publish the results in an XML or HTML format. Is there a way I can publish the results to a particular directory using the same command?
`--result-directory` is not working for me

Comment: I have an trx/html example over here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049029/how-to-get-code-coverage-report-in-donetcore-2-application/59951055#59951055

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can see all the `dotnet test` options by executing `dotnet test --help`.  One of the options is `-l, --logger`, which gives some great information:

```
Specify a logger for test results.
Examples:
Log in trx format using a unqiue file name: --logger trx
Log in trx format using the specified file name: --logger "trx;LogFileName=<TestResults.trx>"
More info on logger arguments support:https://aka.ms/vstest-report
```

That support link https://aka.ms/vstest-report, has the full information.

So to answer your specific question, you can say

`dotnet test -l:trx;LogFileName=C:\temp\TestOutput.xml`

To publish the results to a particular directory.

Another option is setting MSBuild properties in your test.csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VSTestLogger>trx</VSTestLogger>
  <VSTestResultsDirectory>C:\temp</VSTestResultsDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Which tells the logger to put the file in the `C:\temp` directory.

Comment: I cannot create a fixed report file, this dotnet test always append a trailing timestamp `Results File: C:\myapp\results_2019-04-08_14-24-38-379.trx`. I wanted to be `C:\myapp\results.trx` as expected for `dotnet test myapp.csproj --logger trx;LogFileName=C:\temp\results --no-build --no-restore --configuration Release --verbosity q`

Comment: @Eric Erhardt, where could I find the documentation for setting the MSBuild properties in your test.csproj? I have looked and looked, but cannot find any info. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if there is official documentation, I can't find it either. However, I found the properties by looking at how the `dotnet test` command invokes the project. See https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/a936ffd2056383dfcd2dd028cc1676b5c62c7654/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-test/TestCommandParser.cs#L55

Comment: FYI, I had trouble running with `LogFileName` until I wrapped full option in quotation marks, e.g. `-l:"trx;LogFileName=testresult.xml"`. Also of note: when directory is not specified, the file goes into a `TestResults` folder.

Comment: What does trx stand for?

Comment: https://fileinfo.com/extension/trx. I'm not 100% certain, but my guess would be "test result xml".

Answer (score 35):

After stumbling on the same problem (I wanted to publish test results in JUnit format), I ended up finding the [JUnitTestLogger NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JUnitTestLogger/).

It was a matter of installing it:

```
dotnet add package JUnitTestLogger --version 1.1.0
```

And then running the tests as:

```
dotnet test --logger "junit;LogFilePath=path/to/your/test/results.xml"
```

Edit: Check the [more recent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72481420/687420) answer below, which uses JunitXml.TestLogger by Shane Rich.

Comment: Tax, I needed the xunit xml logger and since the "dotnet xunit" command is not longer supported as an external command line tool. Your post led me to find "XunitXml.TestLogger", thanks much, now I am using dotnet test --logger:"xunit;LogFilePath=test_result.xml" to which works for what I needed.

Comment: I always get the following error: `No test logging was found with AssemblyQualifiedName, URI, or FriendlyName "junit"` Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure to run dotnet restore in the environment where you are executing the tests so that the junit assembly is available on the path.

Comment: works good, thanks for sharing.how to output all unit tests projects under a solution file, seems like the output junit report always be last unit test project.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get this to work using the syntax provided in the answer of [Eric Erhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49922944/120453).

Using the TRX Logger examples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/report.md#syntax-of-default-loggers) I was able to recreate the correct syntax.

`dotnet test --logger:"trx;LogFileName=C:\Temp\TestResults.xml" MyLibraryToTest.dll`

```
$ dotnet test --logger:"trx;LogFileName=C:\Temp\TestResults.xml" MyLibraryToTest.dll
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.8.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}) on port 51459
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Results File: C:\Temp\TestResults.xml

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: 7 s - MyLibraryToTest.dll (net5.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

I had success today with the nuget package JunitXml.TestLogger, version 3.0.114:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/JunitXml.TestLogger/

To add as a dependency:
`dotnet add package JunitXml.TestLogger --version 3.0.114`

Once added as a dependency it was simply a matter of executing:
`dotnet test --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=dotnet-test-result.xml"`

At today's date JunitXml.TestLogger has four times as many stars as the nuget package JUnitTestLogger mentioned in another answer. JunitXml.TestLogger is being actively maintained, whereas JUnitTestLogger has not been touched for 2 years.