# Bamboo: How to run xunit tests (Script task), then feed it to "xunit parser"

Tags: bamboo, xunit.net

I configured xunit parser task under my project's Bamboo plan, I ran my plan:
Starting task 'Xunit' of type 'com.wwwlicious.xunit.xunit:xunitParser' Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found.

It dawns on my *xunit **parser*** only parses test result produced somehow from prev steps?

I tried to add a script task to run xunit tests manually: https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started/netcore/cmdline

```
C:\SomeApplication>dotnet test -l:trx;LogFileName=SomeApplTests.xml
Build completed.
Test run for C:\SomeApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\YI.LS.Test.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Starting test execution, please wait...
Total tests: 20. Passed: 20. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Successful.
Test execution time: 4.3114 Seconds
```

So, okay - I can configure a Bamboo **Script task** to run "dotnet test", it'd produce SomeApplTests.xml under "**TestResult**" folder. 
Now the challenge is: how to feed it to **xunit parser**? Also trx logger also no good, prolly need xunit logger https://github.com/spekt/xunit.testlogger

Thanks

**References:**
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1216522/xunit-net-parser?hosting=server&tab=support
https://github.com/wwwlicious/wwwlicious.bamboo.xunit/issues/6
[How to publish results using dotnet test command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917144/how-to-publish-results-using-dotnet-test-command)

https://github.com/spekt/xunit.testlogger

Answer (score 0):

Answer is found:

You need install in test project "XunitXmlTestLogger" (https://github.com/spekt/xunit.testlogger)
Then configure a Script task:
dotnet test -l:"xunit;LogFileName=Test.xml"
You need set Working Directory to point at your test project, for example: MySoln\MyTestProj

Then configure your xUnit.net Parser task in Bamboo, with xUnit Test Results File/Directory to point at: MySoln\MyTestProj*.xml (Default is: artifacts/**/*.xml)

https://github.com/wwwlicious/wwwlicious.bamboo.xunit/issues/6